# jQuery - Cancel $.post to prevent queuing

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, event-handling

OK, So I am creating a entire web app using AJAX with some local storage etc.

The issue I am having is sometimes I double click, or click tabs back and forth quickly which invoke a $.post call.

Problem lies when the callbacks are fired, they are called back and keep overwritting eachother until the last call has came back.

Obviously that is a problem. What I need to do is cancel current POST calls and just get the last callback.

I have tried:

```
// Make Call:

if(call != undefined){
    call.abort();
}
var call = $.post(url,{do:'stuff'},function(response){
     // callback stuff:
},'json');
```

Keeps saying its undefined regardless, I rather use .POST than .AJAX if possible.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is there a typo in your code around 'stuff'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply unbind the click event on click, re-bind it on callback.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do if canceling doesn't catch all your pending XHRs: increment a counter and pass it to your backend to keep old responses from clobbering new ones.  Just have your backend include the counter value in the response, and then your callback can compare it to the local counter before overwriting.